# Does this code for creating C-like structure work? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, struct

I began to learn Javascript because I had to adapt an application I did in Java in AJAX.
But I had some problem, especially with the creation of C-like structures.
After a few researches, I found a code. I adapted this code to the code below. Does this work?

Thank you in advance and have a good day!

```
var Man {
    standingID:"",
    leftID:[]
    rightID:[]
};

var tmp = new Man();

tmp.standingID = "C:\\**";
tmp.leftID.push ("1");

var tmpD = tmp.standingID;
```

Comment: *"Does this work?"* - Well what happened when you ran it? MDN's [Working With Objects article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) might help you see where you've gone wrong.

Comment: "C-like structures"? What is that supposed to mean? Why do you think that's a good approach to solving your problem? What are you trying to do? Are you sure you're not doing something that should be on the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do something like this:

```
function Man () {
    this.standingID = "";
    this.leftID = [];
    this.rightID = [];
};

var tmp = new Man();

tmp.standingID = "C:\\**";
tmp.leftID.push ("1");

var tmpD = tmp.standingID;
```

You should try running your code first, easy (dirty) way to quickly test something is to open the developer console in the browser and paste it into the console and see what happens.

Here is a [link](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/) explaining more about type definition in JavaScript

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think about that solution, it seem weird in my predilection langages.. ^^ But this solve each of my problems!

Comment: Yeah it's not the conventional way of doing things, I've got a heavy .NET and C++ background so I found the function-type thing really confusing at first

Answer (score 0):

No, it wouldn't work, like that. Check this out:

```
function Man(sID) {
  this.standingID = sID; this.leftID = []; this.rightID = [];
  this.addToLeftID = function(a){
    this.leftID.push(a);
    return this;
  }
  this.addToRightID = function(a){
    this.rightID.push(a);
    return this;
  }
}
```

You can do this:

```
var tmp = new Man;
tmp.standingID = 'C:\\**'; tmp.leftID.push('1');
console.leg(tmp.leftID[0]); // String '1'
```

or:

```
var tmp = new Man('C:\\**');
tmp.addToLeftID(1).addToRightID('wft');
console.log('leftID: '+tmp.leftID+'; rightID: '+tmp.rightID); // leftID: 1; rightID: wtf
```